# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () using Angular, deploying with GitHub Pages

Tags: css, angular, typescript, deployment, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my first website using Angular and Github Pages. It deploys successfully, but I get the console error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" at "home: 1", "home" referring to my home page component. I have noticed that all aspects of my webpage seem to be working except for the app.component.css file. My website works perfectly when run locally, and when deployed, all my other CSS files are working just fine. I have searched all over the internet, but I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you’re deploying the project to a Github project page you’ll need to set the baseHref property as the repository name. The baseHref will be used for all relative URLs on your site. You could specify the baseHref as part of the project architect deploy options in the angular.json file. Or just pass it as the --base-href flag to the ng deploy command.

Also, I hope you referred official page to mitigate the issue - https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages